# How to show and add data with Single Linked list object in C++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I want to make a class called Bike with the elements name, height and color but I want to associate a single linked list. The program will return the price of the Bike.

I want the user to be able to enter up to 5 bikes.

I am confused about the part where I have to add the bike data and show them.

This is what I have so far. Can you please guide me through.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Bike
{
private:
    string* name;
    string color;
    double height;
    double price;
    bike * node;
public:
    void entry(Bike *head);
    void display(Bike *current);
    void quit();
    void initializeObject();
};



void Bike::entry(Bike *head)
{
    Bike obj;
    obj.initializeObject();
    head = &obj;
}

void Bike::display(Bike *current)
{
    cout << "The list contains :";
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << current->head;
        current = current->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: instead of `string* name`, do just `string name`.

Comment: I'm not sure at which SO site this question would be appropriate. You could maybe try code review. Here at SO main site the questions should better be about concrete reproducible problems with single answers. An alternative is to post to Usenet, e.g. the **comp.lang.c++** group. You can access it via Google Groups (but it's better to use e.g. Thunderbird as Usenet client and e.g. free Eternal September server) (oh, if you're using Opera browser, as I recall it has a built-in Usenet client, along with also an IRC client, but I may be wrong, not even sure if Opera exists as such any more).

Comment: You should learn how to use pointers first. This code just won't work at all due to numerous errors while using pointers.

Comment: There can be lot of things here , like if there are 10 Bikes which 5 Bikes do you want to show user etc. . if you want to filter on the basis of price etc. May be a more better way would be to create a multimap with price id and object of Bike ( for each different Bike ) and then based on user input of price iterate and show them the same.

Comment: I want the user to be able to add just 5 bikes and I want to show just 5 of them

Comment: I will add the function for calculation and everything. For now I just want to know how can I store class data. I know how to store one value but what about many values ???

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf this would not be a good fit on CodeReview.SE until the code worked as expected. See [How do I ask a good question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Make a different class for multiple bikes.
For example:

```
class Bike {
public:
string name;
...
/*..data and functions for single bike..*/
}

class Bikes {
Bike *head;
public:
void entry(Bike);
....
/* functions */
}
```

In the `main()` function you will have to use the `Bikes` class.

Comment: I will modify my question maybe you can help me better